# How can i use the camera to add the picture to a form?

Tags: ios, camera

Hi I would like to know how i can add the camera to an Online form.

For example users add their info name,title, etc...
and also they can add a photo.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean access the iPhone camera through a web page?  This is not currently possible.

Comment: No i know the camera can't be call by a web page. But what i want is create a form where the user can put their info and add a picture.      for a example: form--> ask for upload a picture or take a picture----summit the form together with the picture. is there anyway? kind like facebook call the camera

Comment: You can not upload an image from the cameral roll to a web page either.  If you log into Facebook from mobile Safari, you can see that you can not upload an image from a web page.  The alternative that Facebook has is to email a photo to them as an attachment.

Comment: Good Answer thank you. I knew you can't upload on a browser but i didn't know the method this other app's use this is really helpful

Comment: Let's clarify, in your original question, was the goal to use a web page or an iPhone app to upload a photo?

Comment: I was trying to do booth using a web page with a Form and some how add a picture to the form. Therefore all i need is the best way to integrate booth using the web page & the iphone camera functionality.